# Why can't I assign const int in struct constructor?

Tags: c++

Why can't I do this in C++?

```
struct SomeStruct
{
public:
    SomeStruct(const int someInt)
    {
        m_someInt = someInt;
    }

private:
    const int m_someInt;
};
```

Should the private field just be a regular integer?

Comment: `const` members can only be initialized in member initializer lists: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list (or using default values since C++11)

Comment: You can't assign to a `const int`, period. If you don't want your private field to be const, don't make it const.

Comment: Same reason why you can't do `const int i; i = 1;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're assigning `someInt` to `m_someInt`, which is illegal. But initialization is okay.

```
struct SomeStruct
{
public:
    SomeStruct(const int someInt) : m_someInt(someInt)
    {

    }

private:
    const int m_someInt;
};
```

More info: [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Answer (score 0):

Value cannot be assigned to a `const` storage. It can be only initialized. In case of class member variable it would be done in  initialization list.

```
struct SomeStruct
{
public:
    SomeStruct(const int someInt) : m_someInt(someInt)
    {

    }

private:
    const int m_someInt;
};
```

Sometimes  in-class initialization is enough:

```
template <int  Val>
struct SomeStruct
{
public:

private:
    const int m_someInt = Val;
};
```

Usually confusion stems from  the fact that programmer doesn't see difference between two cases:

```
// 1) Declaring storage of int object that initially  contains value 5
int a = 5; // It's a declaration.

// 2) Declaring storage of int object that contains undetermined value
int b; // Declaration 
b = 5; // Assigning a value to it. It's a statement.
```

In your case `m_someInt = someInt;` is a statement that expects lvalue before `=`, and `m_someInt` is not a legal lvalue because it is `const`.